# Extract tar.gz file and save again extracted file using Google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to extract tar.gz file at google drive and then want to save it again at google drive. I am using google colaboratory. Can you give some guidance how it works

```
import shutil
shutil.unpack_archive("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/train_dataset.tar.gz", "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/FYP_dataset")
```

this one gives error `No such file or directory: 'train_dataset.tar.gz'`

Comment: You assume the gz file is in your current directory but its not. Is it in /content/drive somewhere?

Comment: @tdelaney I have copy the path. It is there

Comment: Colab has terminal at the bottom left too. You can just use that.

Comment: Also use `ls` to make sure the file is there first. Since there's a chance that the actual name has something like (1) in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. Sometimes it may be fixed your issue. Give your file name with its destination where you want to extract the tar file in Google Drive.

***Flags***

- -x : Extract a tarball.
- -v : Verbose output or show progress while extracting files.
- -f : Specify an archive or a tarball filename.
- -C : Specify a different directory to extract
- -z : Decompress and extract the contents of the compressed archive created by gzip program (tar.gz extension).

  ```
  #run this cell extract_tar.gz files

     !tar -xzvf "/content/drive/path/input_file_name.tar.gz" -C "/content/drive/path/output_folder/"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If it is in your Google drive, you need to access it as follows:

```
from google.colab import drive
import shutil

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
shutil.unpack_archive("gdrive/My Drive/train_dataset.tar.gz", "/content/gdrive/My Drive/FYP_dataset")
```

Comment: If your dataset has a different name, or is in a folder, you will need to change the filepath after the `"gdrive/My Drive/"` to the correct path within your drive.

Comment: yes my dataset in  'gdrive/MyDrive/` and dataset name is `train_dataset`'